# how to compare environment for equality in R

Tags: r, frame, environment

I would like to check if the current environment is the global environment in R.  However, direct comparison doesn't seem to work with evironments.  What is the best way to do this?

```
#doesn't work
sys.frame() == .GlobalEnv
```

Comment: use `identical`. `==` is for vector comparison.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Matthew Plourde's solution:

```
> identical(sys.frame(),.GlobalEnv)
[1] TRUE
```

You can also check names, though this might be less reliable:

```
> environmentName(sys.frame())=="R_GlobalEnv"
[1] TRUE
```

Comment: and `all.equal` if you just want to check whether 2 different environments both have the same contents

Answer (score 0):

Both print and cat return <environment: "an address"> but can't be used for comparison. However format seems to do the job.

Just use format (envir1) == format (envir2)