# Detect if environment is global environment

Tags: r

Sometimes it may be useful to detect if the environment is the global environment or not and act accordingly.  I have come up with what I believe is a way to detect the environment and test if it's the global environment.  I just don't want to be reinventing the wheel if there's a better way or if this has holes etc.  Is there some sort of built in R method to do what `global_test` does below or a better approach?

```
global_test <- function() {
    environmentName(parent.frame(n = 1)) == "R_GlobalEnv"
}

global_test()

lapply(1:10, function(i) {
    global_test()
})

fun <- function() global_test()
fun()
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14491523/how-to-compare-environment-for-equality-in-r

Comment: At first I thought this was a duplicate and voted to close but the answer to that question doesn't appear to do the same thing.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I would simplify your life a little and use `identical`:

```
global_test <- function() {
    identical( parent.frame(n = 1) , globalenv() )
}
```

And I *think* this should be slightly 'safer' than doing a character comparison because you can do this:

```
e <- new.env()
attr(e,"name") <- "R_GlobalEnv"

#  And then...
environmentName(e)
#[1] "R_GlobalEnv"
```

And as pointed out by @eddi, using `.GlobalEnv` may also not be desirable because one can do:

```
.GlobalEnv <- 1
identical( parent.frame(n = 1) , .GlobalEnv )
#[1] FALSE
```

This use of `identical` is in fact one of the examples from the help page on `?identical`:

```
## even for unusual R objects :
identical(.GlobalEnv, environment())
```

So even if we try to trick R the function still works:

```
e <- new.env()
attr(e,"name") <- "R_GlobalEnv"
.GlobalEnv <- 1
global_test()
#[1] TRUE
```

Comment: Perfect.  Yeah the character comparison bothered me but didn't think to use `identical` and compare the environments directly.

Comment: @eddi true. Perhaps `globalenv()` would be safer. I'll update.

Comment: @hadley True, true. This-is-R. Do you have a bulletproof suggestion?

Comment: @SimonO101 don't worry about people overriding functions - i.e. you don't need the part of your answer after the first code block.

Comment: I thought I'd show the context this was used in for future searchers.  [Here](https://github.com/trinker/reports/blob/master/R/is.global.R) is the inclusion of this function in a package.  [Here](https://github.com/trinker/reports/blob/master/R/new_report.R) is how I used it as an argument to a function (see the open argument).

Answer (score 1):

Maybe `sys.nframe`?

```
sys.nframe() == 0L
#[1] TRUE

fun <- function() {
  sys.nframe() == 0L
}

fun()
#[1] FALSE
```

Comment: `sys.nframe()` will never return zero inside a function body, right?

Comment: Of course not, only when called in the global environment. And detecting that was the task, no? Detecting if a function is called in the global environment is a different task.